# How to Set Initial Value For Creating An Index Of Returns With cumprod() in R?

Tags: r

I have a series of returns over some period, let's say daily returns:

```
> Z <-cbind(rnorm(10)*.01)
> Z
               [,1]
 [1,] -0.0095401182
 [2,]  0.0119037893
 [3,]  0.0001539471
 [4,] -0.0087361367
 [5,] -0.0127281577
 [6,] -0.0031177198
 [7,] -0.0041689219
 [8,] -0.0066547279
 [9,]  0.0156863175
[10,] -0.0126733237
```

Next, I create an investment index with cumprod() that represents the return on an initial $1 investment based on return series Z:

```
> ZZ <-cbind((cumprod(1+Z)*1))
> ZZ
           [,1]
 [1,] 0.9904599
 [2,] 1.0022501
 [3,] 1.0024044
 [4,] 0.9936473
 [5,] 0.9810000
 [6,] 0.9779415
 [7,] 0.9738645
 [8,] 0.9673837
 [9,] 0.9825584
[10,] 0.9701061
```

How do I edit the code for creating index ZZ so that the resulting output shows an initial value of 1.00?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the first return zero:

```
cumprod(1+c(0,rnorm(10)*.01))
```

Or divide all elements by the first value:

```
ZZ <- ZZ/ZZ[1,1]
```

Comment: That's it. Thank you! One more question. How do I set initial values to other amounts? Let's say 10 is the initial value. In that case, is this correct:  cumprod(1+c(10,rnorm(10)*.01))

Comment: @JPP: no, that initial value would be 11, not 10. This would set it to 10: `cumprod(c(10,1+rnorm(10)*.01))`.

Comment: Ah, so simple... in retrospect. Thanks again, Joshua. Appreciate your wide-ranging knowledge on these topics. Keep up the great work!

Answer (score 1):

The most direct way is to just add a `1` at the start of `ZZ`:

```
ZZ <- cbind(c(1, cumprod(1+Z)))
```

Comment: Yet another solution. Thanks. It's always helpful to have a plan B. Appreciate it.